# Best way to repeated timer task interval in android

Tags: java, android, timer, intervals

In my android app one timer runs(repeated) with an interval X. Now I want to change the timer interval. For this do i need to cancel the timer and create new timer with my new frequency? 
 If yes, what is there any way to change timer interval without cancelling it?

Currently I change the timer interval by cancelling and creating a new timer with new interval. But sometimes it gives me problem. After cancelling the timer it does not become null.

I want to know is the best method to change the interval of repeated timer task? Will there any memory leak if I do like above?

Comment: i think you can simply declare the interval variable as Global and change value when needed which will change timer task's interval also?

Comment: What do you mean by "After cancelling the timer it does not become null"?  Do you mean calling `Timer.cancel()` I assume you are using `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask`.  If so, cancel simply prevents a TimerTask from running (again) but does not stop it if it's currently running.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? if yes then consider it to accept as your answer

Comment: Did it solve..either post your answer or mark any answer as accepted if you solved it